# Is there a way to get rendering details of a sitecore item via Sitecore item Odata services?

Tags: odata, itemservice

We have a requirement to migrate content pages from Sitecore to AEM. For this we are using Sitecore Odata services approach. But this only provides information about page item fields and not renderings and their datasources; that are being applied onto that page.

To migrate the content pages from classic Sitecore to AEM it requires component details as well.

We have option to retrieve the component details through layout services as well but that is not part of classic Sitecore.

Is there a way to get rendering details of a Sitecore item via Sitecore item Odata services in classic Sitecore (Sitecore without any third party module installation) ?

Answer (score 0):

Whatever I learned about the `Odata Service`, I am not sure, if is there any call that you can give you the details of the rendering. But what I checked is, that you can retrieve the `Sitecore StandardFields` and you can use the field `__Renderings` or `__Final Renderings` to get the details of the `renderings` applied on the item including the `data source`.

So if you call the API like this.

```
http://sitecore10.1sc.dev.local/sitecore/api/ssc/aggregate/content/Items('{27F07929-9DF9-4E3E-9AC3-809AE7EBACCA}')?sc_apikey={11EB9EFA-CCDA-4D52-9FC5-2C37AF408FAE}&$expand=Fields,StandardFields
```

You will get the response with this field like this.

```
        {
            "Id": "f1a1fe9e-a60c-4ddb-a3a0-bb5b29fe732e",
            "Name": "__Renderings",
            "DisplayName": "Renderings",
            "Value": "<r xmlns:p=\"p\" xmlns:s=\"s\" p:p=\"1\"><d id=\"{FE5D7FDF-89C0-4D99-9AA3-B5FBD009C9F3}\" s:l=\"{6A6D1F6B-F1DE-4487-9A9A-BBA514EDBE34}\"><r uid=\"{43222D12-08C9-453B-AE96-D406EBB95126}\"><p:d /></r><r uid=\"{CF044AD9-0332-407A-ABDE-587214A2C808}\"><p:d /></r><r uid=\"{4C4D23A8-896B-49C3-852C-18148E258669}\" p:before=\"*\" s:ds=\"{331C9A20-107F-4560-8587-6344C25BE28F}\" s:id=\"{DA10E289-673B-4010-AB9F-48BE3A013E84}\" s:par=\"\" s:ph=\"main\" s:ccb=\"Clear on publish\" /><r uid=\"{4EAEEF0F-CD17-41BE-B162-16FEEC96DBA8}\" p:after=\"*[1=2]\" s:ds=\"{A6D556CB-3AC2-462F-82A2-921AF7ACC1B7}\" s:id=\"{3994F001-C8C7-4BAF-B7D4-778B760FC02A}\" s:par=\"Skip Link Class=skip-link&amp;RenderingIdentifier\" s:ph=\"main\" s:ccb=\"Clear on publish\" /><r uid=\"{B343725A-3A93-446E-A9C8-3A2CBD3DB489}\"><p:d /></r></d></r>",
            "ContainsStandardValue": false,
            "Description": "",
            "Title": "Renderings",
            "Tooltip": "Defines the shared presentation details",
            "Type": "layout",
            "Validation": "",
            "ValidationText": ""
        }
```

You can use the Value field to retrieve the necessary information. And to know about how to read the `Rendering XML Raw Value`, you can follow this article.

https://www.sitecorespark.com/blog/2021/3/understanding-rendering-and-final-rendering-xml-raw-values

Hope this makes sense.